# PHP - Drop Down lists turn empty after error

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a php file named "add_order.php". It takes three inputs, two inputs (Store and Customer) come from the selections of two corresponding drop-down lists, and the last input (Date) come from user's manual input. 
    If the Date is left empty when submit, the page gives an error and displays the input fields again underneath the error message for users to redo the inputs. However, The two drop-down lists turn to blank when that happens. Can anyone help?
Thank you.

```
     <?php # add_order.php

     $page_title = 'Add Order';

     include ('mysqli_connect.php');

     // Check if the form has been submitted.
     if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    $errors = array(); // Initialize error array.

    // Check for a customer.
    if (empty($_POST['Customer_ID'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter the customer of the order.';
    } else {
        $customer_id = $_POST['Customer_ID'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE Customer_ID=$customer_id ORDER BY Last_N ASC";
        $result = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
        $customer_name=$row['First_N'].' '.$row['Last_N'];
        }
           }

    // Check for a director ID.
    if (empty($_POST['Store_ID'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter the store of the order.';
    } else {
        $store_id = $_POST['Store_ID'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM store WHERE Store_ID=$store_id ORDER BY Store_Name ASC";
        $result = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
        $store_name=$row['Store_Name'];
        }
           }


    // Check for the date of order.
    if (empty($_POST['Order_Date'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter the date of order.';
    } else {
        $order_date = $_POST['Order_Date'];
           }



    if (empty($errors)) { // If everything's okay.

        // Add the order to the database.

        // Make the query.
        $query = "INSERT INTO prescription_orders (Customer_ID, Order_Date, Store_ID) VALUES ('$customer_id', '$order_date', '$store_id')";     
        $result = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $query); // Run the query.
        if ($result) { // If it ran OK.

            // Print a message.
            echo '<h1 id="mainhead">Success!</h1>
        <p>You have added:</p>';

           echo "<table>
        <tr><td>Customer_ID:</td><td>{$customer_id}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Order_Date:</td><td>{$order_date}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Store_ID:</td><td>{$store_id}</td></tr>

        </table>";

        $order_id = mysqli_insert_id($dbc); // Retrieve the id number of the newly added record
        echo'<a href="http://localhost/cvs/add_order_item.php?id=' . $order_id . '">Add a item to this order</a>';
        exit();

        } else { // If it did not run OK.
            echo '<h1 id="mainhead">System Error</h1>
            <p class="error">The movie could not be added due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>'; // Public message.
            echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br /><br />Query: ' . $query . '</p>'; // Debugging message.
            exit();
        }

    } else { // Report the errors.

        echo '<h1 id="mainhead">Error!</h1>
        <p class="error">The following error(s) occurred:<br />';
        foreach ($errors as $msg) { // Print each error.
            echo " - $msg<br />\n";
        }
        echo '</p><p>Please try again.</p><p><br /></p>';

    } // End of if (empty($errors)) IF.


    mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.

     } // End of the main Submit conditional.
     ?>







     <?php 
      if (isset($_POST['Customer_ID'])) $this_customer_id=$_POST['Customer_ID'];
      if (isset($_POST['Store_ID'])) $this_store_id=$_POST['Store_ID'];
     ?>
     <h2>Add Order</h2>
     <form action="add_order.php" method="post">

     <p>Store: <select name="Store_ID">
     <?php 
     // Build the query
     $query = "SELECT * FROM store ORDER BY Store_Name ASC";
     $result = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $query);
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
     {

     if ($row['Store_ID'] == $this_store_id) {
     echo '<option value="'.$row['Store_ID'].'"                
     selected="selected">'.$row['Store_Name'].'</option>';
     }
     else {
     echo'<option                
     value="'.$row['Store_ID'].'">'.$row['Store_Name'].'</option>';}

     }
     ?>
     </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="add_store.php">Add a new Store</a>
     </p>
    <p>Customer: <select name="Customer_ID">
     <?php 
     // Build the query
     $query = "SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY Last_N ASC";
     $result = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $query);
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
     {

     if ($row['Customer_ID'] == $this_customer_id) {
     echo '<option value="'.$row['Customer_ID'].'" 
     selected="selected">'.$row['First_N'].' '.$row['Last_N'].'</option>';
     }
      else {
     echo'<option value="'.$row['Customer_ID'].'">'.$row['First_N'].' 
     '.$row['Last_N'].'</option>';}

     }
     ?>
     </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="add_customer.php">Add a new 
     Customer</a>
     </p>
     <p>Date of Order: <input type="text" name="Order_Date" size="10" 
     maxlength="10" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['Order_Date'])) echo 
     $_POST['Order_Date']; ?>" />&nbsp;<i>YYYY-MM-DD</i></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Order" /></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
     </form>
     <a href="index.php">Go back to Index Page</a>
```

Comment: remove the `@` from `@mysqli_query` you don't want to suppress errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing your database connection thus causing the problem.

Remove `mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.`

Or move it below

`<a href="index.php">Go back to Index Page</a>`

Also, you can use this:

`<?= isset($_POST['Order_Date'])?$_POST['Order_Date']:'' ?>`

as a shorter version of this:

`<?php if (isset($_POST['Order_Date'])) echo $_POST['Order_Date']; ?>`